# Acpi error namespace lookup failure ae_not_found

Tags: system-installation, acpi

Noone answered how to change graphics driver from recovery mode.

I'm not sure that's the primary problem. I get errors if I try to enable networking in recovery. I get similar errors now trying to boot. I am now trying to reinstall, and getting these exact errors booting from USB install media.

```
Acpi error namespace lookup failure, ae_not_found
Acpi exception ae_not_found during name lookup/catelog
Acpi exception are not found while loading table
Acpi error 1 table load failure, 12 successful

USB 1-1 device descriptor read/64 error -110
Sda no caching mode page found
Sda assuming drive cache: write through
```

If it's regular system boot, not USB, I also get

```
Failed to create unit file run systems generator swapfile.swap as it already exists. Duplicate entry in fstab?
System's systemd-fstab-generator failed with exit status 1.
```

Comment: Did you try de-activating ACPI in the BIOS?
e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/348806/acpi-exception-ae-not-found-infinitely-on-startup#348970

Comment: No, I've reinstalled the OS a 4th time, and did a specific command that mutes some integer like 6 or 8 acpi errors, based on another thread for a different specific model of laptop that had 6 or 8 acpi errors every boot.

Comment: Could you edit and add the output of `inxi -SM && journalctl -k -b0 -p3 | grep -i ACPI && grep acpi /etc/default/grub`?